# how to insert muti select to database

Tags: laravel, select, where-clause

Look at my **code snippet**. i want to insert all values `1,2,3` to database
i have `color table` and `product table`

## These are My Tables

**colors:**
| A header | Another header |
| -------- | -------------- |
| First    | row            |
| Second   | row            |

**product:**
| id| name| color_id|
|---- |------| -----|
| 1   | Phone| 1    |
| 2   |Laptop| 2    |

in the `product table` How can i select more than one color to the product
i tried to make this but it failed
| id| name| color_id|
|---- |------| -----|
| 1   | Phone| 1  3    |
| 2   |Laptop| 2  4    |

i want to give the product two colors because i want to show the colors the product is has using the code in `ColorController`

## These are My Controllers

**ColorController:**

```
         class productColorController extends Controller {
                  ...

           public function store(Request $request) {
     $colors = collect($request->color); // Here it gives the color are getting from the multi select you can see it in code snippet
    
         $color = productColor::create([ 
       'color' => $colors['color'], //  here i want to create all of the color are getting from request and save to database but when i try this i see only one color was saved to database
        
       ]); 
    
    }
// The code to show all colors
$getcolor = productColor::where('id' , 1)->get(); // I Want To Show All Colors User selected in id 1
    }
```

**The conclusion of the question: when  user selected multi colors i want to save it in database and show all the colors to admin**

```html
<select data-placeholder="Please Choose Color" multiple name="" class="select2 form-control">
                                        <optgroup label="Please Choose Color">
                                          <option value='black'>
                                          Black
                                          </option>
                                           <option value='white'>
                                          White
                                          </option>
                                        
                                           <option value='gray'>
                                          Gray
                                          </option>
                                           <option value='blue'>
                                          Blue
                                          </option>
                                        
                                       >
                                        </optgroup>
                                    </select>
```

Comment: best way is to create one to many relation, create pivot table and make a relation with products and colors.

Comment: yes i have one to many relation but i can't save to color in the table

Comment: You need many to many, not one to many relationship

Comment: @workservice please can you give me an example

Comment: I have answered below @BlexChex Implement that and it will work like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want a product to have more than one color?
In this case you can build a pivot table. Basically it's an intermediate table between 2 tables and you can assign more than 1 color to your product in this case.

```
    Schema::create('color_product', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->integer('color_id');
        $table->integer('product_id');
    });
```

In `Product` Model:

```
public function colors()
{
return $this->belongsToMany(Color::class);
}
```

In `color` Model:

```
public function products()
{
return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

To retrieve the relationships:

IE:

```
$product = Product::first();
$product->colors;
```

More on documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

add a name to select element and it is better to create another table for colors and create a realationship between product table and color table

```
<select data-placeholder="Please Choose Color" multiple name="color[]"
```

and this article will help you
[How to Store Multiple Select Values in Laravel?](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-store-multiple-select-values-in-laravelexample.html)